# Lost form validation when changed button type

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which validates that an option is selected using a returned boolean from a function:

```
<form  id="checkoutForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" name="paypal">
```

And I was submitting the form with this standard image button:

```
<input name="submit" type="image"  src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" value="Checkout">
```

However I've been updating and am using a CSS button instead so submit the form as so:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="float:right;" class="shopbutton" onclick="document.forms['checkoutForm'].submit();">Checkout with PayPal</a>
```

I can just use the standard button like so:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit"  class="shopbutton" value="Checkout">
```

But this causes me some other small issues and I'd like to know how to ensure the form validates using the other method?

TIA

Edit: I should also mention that when using the `<a href` type button that the button is declared outside of the `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are bypassing the `onsubmit` when *directly* submitting the form with javascript. This is one example why client-sided validation is **bad**.

One solution to your problem would be to append your `a` link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="float:right;" class="shopbutton" onclick="validateForm()">Checkout with PayPal</a>
```

And then just add some error count to the validation function, and submit within the function if no errors were found, like so:

```
function validateForm() {
    var errors = 0;
    if(inputFieldHere.value.length<3) errors++;
    if(errors) return false; //Or display some error or something
    else document.forms["checkoutForm"].submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, elegant and quick solution. Its not a major validation but I understand what your saying about client-side validation being bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>element</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkme() {
        if (!document.form.agree.checked) {
            missinginfo = "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions\n Please tick the box and try again.";
            alert(missinginfo);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert("Text information");
            return true;
        }
    }

  function submit_form()
  {
        if(checkme() == true)
        {
            document.forms["form"].submit();
        }
  }
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return checkme();">
      <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" value="agree_terms" class="terms">
      <label for="agree">&nbsp;I&acute;ve read terms and conditions and I&acute;m ready to shop</label>
      <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="#" style="float:right;" class="shopbutton" onclick="submit_form();">Submit form</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keeping `<input>` button inside the form as hidden (e.g. with `style="display:none;"`).

This way you may keep `<a>` to submit form with onclick, and keep validation in place (I wouldn't be surprised if validation code looks for some reason for `<input type="submit" />` inside a form)

Comment: Just tried that, sad to say it still submits the form when it shouldn't.

Comment: hmm.. and what about `<a .. onclick="validateForm() && document.forms['checkoutForm'].submit();">`?